# Ajax HTML Editor - Get Markup

Tags: ajax, html-editor

How can I get the HTML code (markup) that the AJAX HTMLEditor creates?

I'm trying to use the editor in order to transform rich text into a full html file. Then, the file will be used to write a SQL statement in order to insert it into a database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Content property.